# Communication between Jint and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jint

I am looking for a way to communicate (back and forth) between Jint and C#.

Is there a way? I have no problem of running JavaScripts in Jint after loading them to the engine but I still have an issue getting the callbacks on the other hand - from the JavaScript back to C#(maybe using some kind of ObjectForScripting? or other predefined settings?)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In C#, provide a class with a method you want to run.

```
public class JavaScriptHelper {
    public string Method(string input) {
        return String.Concat("Hi", input);
    }
}
```

Then pass the class to the engine.

```
var engine = new Engine();
engine.SetValue("helper", new JavaScriptHelper());
var source = @" var result = helper.Method('Hello');"
engine.Run(source);
```